# Symfony querybuilder with manyTomany relationship and count function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a manyTomany relationship in my course entity and in my user entity.
The course entity has the value members and the user entity gameRounds. In my course entity, I also set the maxMembers value as an integer.
Now I want to make a doctrine query with the querybuilder and the values k for course and u for users that tests whether the number of course members is less than the value maxMembers.

```
 $qb->innerJoin('k.members','u');
    $qb->andWhere('k.id in (u.gameRounds)');
    $qb->addSelect('count(u.id) as countValue');
    $qb->andWhere('countValue <  :maxMembers');
    $qb->setParameter('maxMembers','k.maxMembers');
```

I have testet this Code. But the server gives me an error with

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 144 near 'gameRounds) AND': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

now i am a little further:

```
   $qb->join('k.members','u');
   $qb->having('count(u) < k.maxMembers');
   $qb->groupBy('k.id');
```

this seems to work, but only with entries that have at least one value in the table. How can I compare the entries that have no value in the table and where the value of count is empty?
i tried it with

```
 $qb->having('ISNULL(count(u),0) < k.maxMembers');
```

but there comes an error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 123: Error: Expected known function, got 'ISNULL'
```

Comment: why do you check if k.id is in u.gameRounds ?

Comment: Maybe I can leave that out. But if I do, I'll get another error. An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sclr_10' in 'where clause

Comment: that's because your other where uses "countValue", which isn't a column, but an aggregate, which requires "having" instead of "where".

Comment: When I use having, only an empty array comes out as a result, which can't be right.

Comment: the sql: HAVING sclr_10 < k0_.max_members

Comment: hard to say, have you considered creating an sqlfiddle?

Comment: why do you group by u and not by k? you really should consider an sql fiddle, because if nobody even understands what the query is supposed to do ... this is going to be really hard

Answer (score 0):

```
$qb->leftJoin('k.members','u');
$qb->having('count(u.id) < k.maxMembers');
$qb->groupBy('k.id');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.